# Enter a string into a struct: segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

So far I've been able to answer all all my questions by a dutiful search, but this one has me stumped.

So. I've reduced this code to the minimum necessary to produce the error. Here it is:

```
#include <studio.h>  

struct string {
      char *data;
} s;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Enter a string. ");
    scanf("%s\n", &s.data);
    printf("%s", s.data);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using gcc 4.6.3 and compiling with -Wall -g using classic defensive programming tactics.

I posted this from my phone, so there may be typos and autocorrect madness.

Comment: You haven't initialised the pointer. Also, 2nd line is wrong. without scanf. That's why you are reading null.

Comment: It's `#include <stdio.h>`... Please post your actual code!

Comment: (That is, minimal code -- but code that is as right -- and compileable -- as you can make it.)

Comment: Like I said, my eyes are tired. I'm pretty fried. Yeah, that WAS scanf(%s...  IPhone "fixed" that for me. Sorry. Just assume my code is correct. Circa 1997? What's the fix?

Comment: Still, problem is there.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm am brand new to this forum. Even my comments are truncated due to my big, thick fingers hitting wrong buttons. The code is now edited. Thanks for seeing the most egregious errors in my typing!

Comment: I deeply apologize for my typos. It's hard enough to post here from a mobile device. Sorry to frack you up with a noise to signal ratio out of bounds. Thanks for the input. It's really great that I even got answers.

Comment: @RichardG.Crockett, I just edited your code again. I think this is the way it really is, assuming the `printf` was correct as it was, just the `scanf` was missing. If I was wrong with it, please complain.

Comment: No. You got it. Thanks for grokking what I was trying to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `scanf`, to read as a string using an `unallocated pointer`, specify the `'m'` directive forcing scanf to allocate memory as needed while skipping newline. You are responsible for `freeing the memory` allocated to the string. `scanf` expects the pointer provided to be type `char**`.

```
scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &s.data);
```

The trailing `%*c` reads and discards the trailing newline. (be aware of this if you simply press `[enter]`)

Comment: Hooah! Yep. That worked! Super! But I feel like a script kiddie just copying and pasting. How do I research the %m parameter? I can't even find any reference to that.  This is total news to me. My background is in Perl. Getting under the hood is both the joy and pain of C. Most peculiarly, why is is it that code that worked before now doesn't?

Comment: That is the beauty of C. It is an exact language where there is no `almost` right syntax. This is how C is able to give low level access to the hardware. Every statement and every subpart of a statement have to be right. Any additional time spent digging in the details in C is time well spent. This little gem for `scanf` can be found in `man scanf` (but it isn't near the top :) Glad I could help.

Comment: Well, I surely missed that, so thanks. Time to delve deeply into "man 3 scanf". Meanwhile, up vote me so I have enough karma to at least thank the people who put up awesome answers.

Comment: Done, you have the karma now :)

Comment: Well, I'm not finding that in my implementation. I'm getting that this is some serious guru s**t. On the one hand, I'm going, "Hmm, no wonder it's not obvious, on the other, I'm going, "Well, it should be because this is wicked cool and super important." And thanks for the up vote!

Comment: Well, after not finding that on my probably outdated ubuntu implementation, I went to our 900 pound gorilla friend, aka, "google." Uh Huh. So %m is an awesome form of dynamic malloc. Stupendous. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1. allocate memeory to the pointer before using it

```
s.data = calloc(DATASIZE, sizeof (char));
```

<sup>Recommended Alternative:  `malloc()`</sup>

Point 2. Use `scanf()` to take the input and store it.

```
scanf("%s", s.data);
```

<sup>Recommended Alternative:  `fgets()`</sup>

Please find below is a corrected version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DATASIZE 128

struct string {
      char *data;
} s;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    s.data = calloc(DATASIZE, sizeof (char));
    printf("Enter a string. \n");
    scanf("%s", s.data);
    printf("Input is : %s\n", s.data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As scanf is supposed to write to the places where data is expected, there is no need to prefer `calloc()` over `malloc()`.

Comment: @Sourav. I was so busy messing around last night, I never thanked you for your detailed answer. Yes, fgets is probably the way to go. But I got hung up over something that should have worked but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need allocated the memory by using malloc first.

s.data = malloc(100);

Comment: malloc has nothing to do with it. He is not reading the string in the first place.

Comment: He uses scanf(), although misspeled

Comment: @OrenKishon I don't see any `scanf()` on the question at all. Except, you consider "missing" a special case of "misspelt".

Comment: The code without scanf won't cause a seg-fault as reported, so it must have been missed only in the question code. - @glglgl

Comment: @OrenKishon A `printf("%s", s.data);` with `s.data` mis-initialized will surely segfault. (No, not surely, but probably.) But, as we see, it really was only missing in the Q.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it's in a struct isn't the problem.  The problem is that the pointer data is not initialized, and there's no memory for the stuff to be copied into.

This solves the problem:

```
struct string 
{
 char data [SOMEBIGNUMBER]
} s;
```

and so does this:  keep string as it is, but allocate the space for data in main using malloc.

Comment: Whoa. I'm kinda blown away by all this instant data. You cats are the bomb. But I need to check. Sorry for the typos. Here I am trying to talk and then suddenly, Yah! I'm on REI's website. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in this statement

```
("%s", s.data);
```

there is a typo. I think you mean

```
scanf("%s", s.data);
```

Otherwise

```
("%s", s.data);
```

is an expression with the comma operator that simply returns s.data.

The first problem with your code that you have to allocate memory where you are going to write enetered data.

For example

```
s.data = malloc( 256 * sizeof( char ) );
```

Instead of 256 you may use nay value as you like.

The second problem is that you should use `fgets` instead of `scanf` because using the last is unsafe.

So the main can look like

```
int main( void )
{
    const size_t N = 256;

    s.data = malloc( N * sizeof( char ) );

    s.data[0] = '\0';

    printf("Enter a string (no more than %zu characters). ", N );
    fgets( s.data, N, stdin );

    printf("%s\n", s.data);

    free( s.data );

    return 0;
}
```

Also you may remove the new line character that will be stored in data.s after fgets.

For example

```
size_t len = strlen( s.data );
if ( len && s.data[len - 1] == '\n' ) s.data[len - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: True that. There were some typos. I think I fixed those. Fracking mobile devices and auto correct.

Answer (score 0):

In this use malloc for memory allocation of structure object and char pointer. 
below is corrected code....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct string {
  char *data;
} *s;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   s = (struct string*)malloc(sizeof(struct string));
   s->data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

   printf("Enter a string : ");
   scanf("%s", s->data);
   printf("%s\n", s->data);

   return 0;
}
```